# What does the backslash syntax mean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I recently ran into javascript code that looks like this:

`if(/a=er/i.test(querystring) || /a=nwr/i.test(querystring))`

I am not familiar with the part `/a=er/i` or `/a=nwr/i` syntax. I know that backslashes in javascript are escape characters, but they should be inside strings.

I have been googling and couldn't find an answer. The code executes with not issue, I am just unfamiliar with this syntax.

Comment: Those are forward slashes, not backslashes.  That's a regex literal.

Comment: Those aren't backslashes, first of all `\` is a backslash. They're immediate regexes.

Comment: It's a [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Answer (score 1):

Those are just some Regular Expressions!

Learn more about them from [Mozilla's JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).